# Trouble referencing IE browser instance in stepdefs

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-iedriver

I have an issue with Java/Selenium where I create a IE driver with this line:

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities)

I then reference this with driver.get("somepage") in my first step def. This works fine. I then click a button and move onto another page, which works fine (the browser moves page). However, in my second step definition I'm trying to do:

```
String test = driver.getCurrentUrl();
System.out.println(test);
assert(test.equals(url));
```

IntelliJ just keeps ticking over and execution never completes. I think once I've moved off the first page, it isn't recognising the web driver instance I created in the first step def, and I can't reference any elements on the page. Is there anything I'm missing that is required to pass the webdriver instance from one stepdef to another, or should it be universally accessible by default? I'm not doing anything in my code to kill the instance. thanks in advance.

---

So inside src\main\java\domain\DriverManager, I have:

```
public void openBrowser() {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "IE");
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\SeleniumFiles\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    /*
    Create the ie instance and navigate to page
     */
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
    //driver.get("https://conditions-test.hca.local/home");
}
```

Then inside my stepdef, I reference the webdriver instance:

```
@Given("^I navigate to the conditions home page$")
public void navigateHome()  {
    driver.get("www.google.com");
    System.out.println("Logging on to google as Joe Bloggs");
    String test = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    assert(test.equals("www.google.com"));
}
```

The part that is failing is below. This is in a separate step defs file to the above reference:

```
@Then("^I should be on the (.*) page$")
public void checkURL(String url) {
    String test = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    System.out.println(test) 
    System.out.println(test);
    assert(test.equals(url));
}
```

The runner file just ticks over in the bottom left corner, but I eventually (after half an hour or so!) get this error:

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Can you show us what exactly are you doing??

Comment: Added a bit more detail above Ranjith